# Changes made to Dockerfile aren't always applied when running by docker-compose

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I'm watching *Stephen Grider*'s tutorial about Docker & Kubernetes.
In the module about *Creating a Production-Grade Workflow* there is a React/Node JS example around which concepts are explained. First, project was built via following Linux commands:

```
[root@fedora Desktop]# npm install -g create-react-app
[root@fedora Desktop]# create-react-app frontend
```

Then I `cd`ed into `frontend`, setting it as working directory. I created the following Dockerfile for dev environment (`Dockerfile.dev`):

```
FROM node:alpine

WORKDIR '/app'

COPY package.json .
RUN npm install

COPY . .

CMD ["npm", "run", "start"]
```

For simplicity we used a docker-comspose file in order to run image from the Dockerfile above:

```yaml
# Our docker-compose.yml
version: '3'
services:
  web:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile.dev
    ports:
    - "3000:3000"
    volumes:
    - /app/node_modules
    - .:/app
```

Now all we have to do in order to run the container is to issue the command `docker-compose up`.

It's been said that the `COPY . .` line can be omitted from the `Dockerfile.dev`. This is because we have specified our docker volume to map `/app/<file or folder in container>` to `./<file or folder in Linux host>`. Hence, copying doesn't matter when we are actually accessing them using references to local filesystem of Linux host instead files that are copied into container. The only exception for that mapping is `/app/node_modules` which is not serving as a reference to `./node_modules` and instead is directly accessed from the container's filesystem snapshot.

It works for me. However I see some strange beaviors as I adjust things a little bit more. I go through these steps, respectively:

1. I deleted `COPY package.json .` and `RUN npm install` from `Dockerfile.dev` and ran `docker-compose up --build` that rebuilds the image specified in docker-compose file. I expected to see error as these lines install the server-running dependencies in `/app/node_modules`. The tutorial also said it would get into problem but it didn't!
2. I added back just the `RUN npm install`. This time the change was applied and as expected, `docker-compose up --build` obviously ran into error.
3. I deleted `RUN npm install` again and the result of step 1 repeated again.
4. I deleted `- /app/node_modules` from the `volumes:` section of `docker-compose.yml`. This time, I obviously saw the error I expected in step 1: `sh: react-scripts: not found`
5. I added back `- /app/node_modules` to the `volumes:` section of `docker-compose.yml`. The contents of `docker-compose.yml` and `Dockerfile.env` were exact the same as step 1. Eventually expected error occurred: `sh: react-scripts: not found` !

When talking about results of steps 2-5, I mean the result of `docker-compose up --build` for those steps.
At step 5 everything worked normally as expected, and the problem prevailed until I added back `COPY package.json .` and `RUN npm install` to `Dockerfile.dev`, as was stated in the tutorials.
It seems as if somehow, a cached version of image is used in step 1. In spite of doing the workarounds mentioned about this in similar stackoverflow posts I still get the same result and nothing changes. Can someone explain what happens and why? And is there a way to get the expected error at the very first step?

Answer (score 0):

You should delete the entire `volumes:` block from your Compose file.

The `volumes:` hide everything that's in your image.  Most of the code is bind-mounted from the host system, except that the `node_modules` directory is stored in a Docker named volume.  This explains the behavior of the first couple of steps: even if you don't `RUN npm install` in the Dockerfile, there's still a module tree in the named volume that's being injected at run time.  Similarly, in the last two steps you effectively delete and recreate the named volume, so there's no longer a module tree anywhere that can be used.

Particularly in a production-oriented flow, you don't want this behavior.  If you go to deploy this image, with this setup you've never actually run the code in it.  You also don't usually want to deploy the image and separately deploy its code; that is, you wouldn't have these mounts at runtime.  If you're trying to actively develop this, it should work fine to use Node without Docker for day-to-day development, then introduce this Compose setup for integration testing and deployment.

> It's been said that the `COPY . .` line can be omitted....

Consider what might happen if you removed the custom image entirely:

```yaml
services:
  web:
    image: node:alpine
    working_dir: /app
    command: npm run start
    volumes:
      - /app/node_modules
      - .:/app
```

Now you can invoke this container to install modules and run the application

```bash
docker-compose run web npm install
docker-compose up -d
```

You'll have pretty much exactly the same behavior you see now: the code is on the host, `node_modules` is in a named volume, and nothing in the image is actually used.  But this is really just a roundabout way to use Node, and it's easier in most cases to directly run `npm install; npm run start` on the host.